# How to handle this warning: The Linux source in /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/build has not been configured

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I am trying to install a Sangoma PRI card on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. During installation of the drivers, it gives me this warning, followed by other errors which are a consequence of this issue (or so I think):

```
warning: The Linux source in /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/build 
         has not been configured.
```

Would help any pointers to solve this issue.  I can install this PRI card properly on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as no such warnings are displayed. However,   I need to have it work on 14.04.

The "ls" content of the directory is:

```
   ls /lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/build 
   arch    Documentation  fs       ipc      kernel    mm                  samples   sound   usr
   block   drivers        include  Kbuild   lib       Module.symvers  scripts   tools   virt
   crypto  firmware       init     Kconfig  Makefile  net             security  ubuntu
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to update your kernel to the latest version: 3.19.0-56
May be this solve the problem.

```
apt-get install `uname -r | sed s/25/56/`
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I had installed the sources in some local directory and the driver installation script was expecting the Linux header files in that directory. I installed in /usr/src and the driver installation went through.  But your answer is certainly helpful.